# I can't pass the data from the controller to the view in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I can't pass the data from the controller to the view in CodeIgniter 3. All the thing seem okay. Do I need to put the Controller's part in the index() method?

Donor_Model.php

```
function viewDonors() {
        $query = $this->db->get('donors');
        return $query;
    }
```

Staff.php controller

```
public function viewDonors()
    {

        $this->load->Model('Donor_Model');
        $data['donors'] = $this->Donor_Model->viewDonors();
        $this->load->view('viewdonors', $data);
    }
```

When I try to call the $data in the viewdonors.php view, it shows the $donors as undefined.

[screenshot of viewdonors.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgqx9.png)

Comment: Your IDE is showing it as "undefined". What happens if you actually run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TimBrownlaw is right. Even though the IDE shows an error, the code runs without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your model page to:-

```
function viewDonors() {
    $query = $this->db->get('donors');
    return $query->result();
}
```

As you want to loop through donors data in the view page so you need to return result function in the model.